# Python convert str to int, combining not summing

Tags: python

Trying to sum two items instead of combining them such as 500 for rent, 50 utilities returns 50050 instead of the desired 550.

```
from sys import argv

def bills(rent, utilities):
     raw_input("How much is your rent?") % (rent)
     raw_input("How much are utilities?") % (utilities)

rent = raw_input("How much is your rent? ")
utilities = raw_input("How much are utilities? ")

total = rent + utilities

print total
```

Comment: `int()` and `float()` are basically the first built ins in the docs. Surely it took you more effort to come on here and ask this than spend five seconds reading.

Comment: Google the first part of your question title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse String to Float or Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the `bills()` function is meant to do, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks, tried the following: total = int(rent + utilities) , which didn't work (working version below) - adding in case other newbies have a related issue

Comment: Float or int wasn't my issue (either would be fine), it was getting rid of the combining result

Comment: It's not a great idea to represent amounts of money with floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `int(variable)` if you want an integer from a string

```
total = int(rent) + int(utilities)
```

Comment: Thanks did the following and ended up working:  total = int(rent) + int(utilities)

Comment: @Sean: you can accept the answer once you have what you looked for ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
total = rent + utilities
```

`rent` and `utilities` are both strings, which is why they're being concatenated.

To convert them to integers:

```
total = int(rent) + int(utilities)
```